# Creating a Gradle build file for React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to set up a starter React project. I have used a `create-react-app` to create a starter app. I linked it to our Firebase account, and made a simple page to display stored dummy data.

We initialized the firebase within our project using `firebase init` then installed the following dependencies: firebase cloud functions, firebase firestore.

Here is our App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useState } from "react";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "hidden",
  authDomain: "hidden",
  projectId: "hidden",
  storageBucket: "hidden",
  messagingSenderId: "hidden",
  appId: "hidden"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(firebaseapp);

function App() {
  
  const [firebaseData, updateData] = useState([]);
  //getPreferences(updateData);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>{firebaseData.map(item => <div> {item} </div>)}</div>

        <button onClick={() => getPreferences(updateData)}>Fetch Data</button>
        
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

async function getPreferences(updateData) {
  const q = query(collection(db, "preferences"));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  let data = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    data.push(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
  });
  updateData(data);
}

export default App;
```

We are running the following commands to run the app locally: `npm install`, `npm install firebase`, and `npm start`.

We are trying to create a single Grade build file to package everything which would run all of these commands and allow to launch the app.

We used the following command to initialize Gradle: `gradle init --type basic --dsl groovy --project-name`

Here is what I have for Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 
node {
    version = "16.2.0"
    download = true
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
}
 
task bundle(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}
 
assemble.dependsOn(bundle)
```

And I'm getting the following error when trying to run `gradle`:

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/rkudryashov/Desktop/PartnerUp/build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following
  sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this
  source)

I am trying to make it so all of the dependencies are installed locally when running `gradle` even if a person doesn't have those installed.

Where did we go wrong?